# Optimizing rock, paper, scissors (newbie)

Tags: python, optimization

I am a beginner to python and have tried to make a rock paper scissors game. Please check it and help me optimize or simplify the code by making it shorter.

This is probably the 4th program I have written so it might not be very efficient. I need some feedback on where I can cut down on code length.

```
from random import randint
sc=0 #computer score
sp=0 #player score
inp=False
c=0 #logic variable
t=['rock','paper','scissors']
print("enter 1 for rock\n\t  2 for paper\n\t  3 for scissors")
player=False
while player==False :
    inp=False
    c=3
    computer = t[randint(0, 2)]
    while inp==False:
        inp=input('\n1.rock,2.paper,3.scissors: ')
        if inp=='1':
            player='rock'
        elif inp=='2':
            player= 'paper'
        elif inp=='3':
            player= 'scissors'
        else:
            print("incorrect input!")
            inp=False
    if computer==player:
        print("Computer chose", computer)
        print('tie')
    elif player == 'rock':
        if computer=='paper':
            c=1
        else :
            c=0
    elif player=='paper':
        if computer=='scissors' :
            c=1
        else:
            c=0
    elif player=='scissors':
        if computer=='rock':
            c=1
        else:
            c=0
    else:
        print("that is not a valid input")
        c==2
    if c==1:
        sc+=1
        print("Computer chose", computer)
        print('you lose', computer, 'beats', player)
    elif c==0:
        sp+=1
        print("Computer chose", computer)
        print('you win', player, 'beats', computer)
    p=False
    while p==False:
        p=input('do you want to play again: (y/n) ?')
        if p=="y":
            player=False
        elif p=="n":
            player=True
        else:
            print("incorrect input,please re enter!")
            p=False
print("final score:\ncomputer:",sc,"\nplayer:",sp)
print("the game has ended")
```

Comment: Your code is simpler to [our First Python Game: Rock, Paper, Scissors](https://thehelloworldprogram.com/python/python-game-rock-paper-scissors/) which has suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

where you said:

```
while player==False: #this could be any statement with while (variable)==(true or false)
```

you could change that to:

```
while not player:
```

(if it was `while player == True`, you could put `while player:`)
also when you define all your variables:

```
sc=0 
sp=0 
inp=False
c=0
```

you could cut that down to:

```
sc = 0, sp = 0, inp = False, c = 0
```

on line ~61 you said:

```
else:
    print("incorrect input,please re enter!")
    p=False
```

The `p=False` statement is actually not needed, as `p` was never changed if you chose something other than y or n.
and lastly, on line ~44, you put in:

```
else:
    print("that is not a valid input")
    c==2
```

The `c==2` statement does not assign c to 2, it detects if c is equal to 2. So, if you want to make it work, you need to change it to `c=2`